# Using Python and BeautifulSoup to scrape list from an URL

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to BeautifulSoup so please excuse any beginner mistakes here. I am attempting to scrape an url and want to store list of movies under one date.
Below is the code I have so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get("https://www.imdb.com/calendar?region=IN&ref_=rlm")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
date = soup.find_all("h4")
ul = soup.find_all("ul")
for h4,h1 in zip(date,ul):
    dd_=h4.get_text()
    mv=ul.find_all('a')
    for movie in mv:
        text=movie.get_text()
        print (dd_,text)
        movielist.append((dd_,text))
```

I am getting "AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?"

Expected result in list or dataframe

```
29th May 2020 Romantic
29th May 2020 Sohreyan Da Pind Aa Gaya
5th June 2020 Lakshmi Bomb
and so on
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script will get all movies and corresponding dates to a dataframe:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.imdb.com/calendar?region=IN&ref_=rlm'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

out, last = [], ''
for tag in soup.select('#main h4, #main li'):
    if tag.name == 'h4':
        last = tag.get_text(strip=True)
    else:
        out.append({'Date':last, 'Movie':tag.get_text(strip=True).rsplit('(', maxsplit=1)[0]})

df = pd.DataFrame(out)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
             Date                          Movie
0     29 May 2020                       Romantic
1     29 May 2020       Sohreyan Da Pind Aa Gaya
2    05 June 2020                    Laxmmi Bomb
3    05 June 2020                   Roohi Afzana
4    05 June 2020                        Nikamma
..            ...                            ...
95  26 March 2021       Untitled Luv Ranjan Film
96  02 April 2021                             F9
97  02 April 2021                    Bell Bottom
98  02 April 2021  NTR Trivikiram Untitled Movie
99  09 April 2021                 Manje Bistre 3

[100 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace "ul" with "h1" on the 10th line. And add definition of variable "movielist" ahead.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get("https://www.imdb.com/calendar?region=IN&ref_=rlm")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
date = soup.find_all("h4")
ul = soup.find_all("ul")
# add code here
movielist = []
for h4,h1 in zip(date,ul):
    dd_=h4.get_text()
    # replace ul with h1 here
    mv=h1.find_all('a')
    for movie in mv:
        text=movie.get_text()
        print (dd_,text)
        movielist.append((dd_,text))
print(movielist)
```

Comment: By doing this I am able to get output but that is not right.

Comment: So what do you want it to be?

Comment: I want date followed by movie name. Instead it is giving output: date 29 May 2020 Release Calendar29 May 2020 DVD & Blu-ray Releases29 May 2020 Top Rated Movies. For clarification check from beginiing of output.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't specify a list to receive, and I changed it from 'h1' to 'text capture' instead of 'h4'.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.imdb.com/calendar?region=IN&ref_=rlm")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

movielist = []
date = soup.find_all("h4")
ul = soup.find_all("ui")
for h4,h1 in zip(date,ul):
    dd_=h4.get_text()
    mv=h1.find_all('a')
    for movie in mv:
        text=movie.get_text()
        print (dd_,text)
        movielist.append((dd_,text))
```

The reason the date doesn't match in the output result is that the 'date' retrieved looks like the following, so you need to fix the logic.
There are multiple titles on the same release date, so the release date and number of titles don't match up. I can't help you that much because I don't have the time. Have a good night.

```
29 May 2020
05 June 2020
07 June 2020
07 June 2020 Romantic
12 June 2020
12 June 2020 Sohreyan Da Pind Aa Gaya
18 June 2020
18 June 2020 Laxmmi Bomb
19 June 2020
19 June 2020 Roohi Afzana
25 June 2020
25 June 2020 Nikamma
26 June 2020
26 June 2020 Naandhi
02 July 2020
02 July 2020 Mandela
03 July 2020
03 July 2020 Medium Spicy
10 July 2020
10 July 2020 Out of the Blue
```